# Unable to debug new Hermes React Native app using Chrome DevTools

Tags: ios, react-native, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, react-native-hermes

I am currently working on a new React Native project that uses Hermes as the JavaScript engine. However, I'm facing difficulties when trying to debug the app using Chrome DevTools.

[image]

I have followed the steps mentioned in the React Native documentation and have successfully enabled debugging through the following command:

adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081

After running this command, I can see the app running on my device, but when I try to open Chrome DevTools by typing "chrome://inspect" in the Chrome browser, the app does not appear in the list of available targets.

I have tried the following steps to troubleshoot the issue:

- Ensured that the app is running in debug mode by checking the android:debuggable flag in the AndroidManifest.xml file.
- Restarted the Metro Bundler.
- Restarted my device and computer.
- Updated React Native, Hermes, and Chrome to their latest versions.
- Checked that USB debugging is enabled on my device.
- Tried using a different USB cable and USB port.

Despite trying these steps, I am still unable to debug the app using Chrome DevTools. Any suggestions or insights on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35600